# Select elements from a list of lists using lapply in R

Tags: r, lapply

I have a list of lists called `my_list_of_lists`, from which I want to select a certain number of elements.

- from element 1 of `my_list_of_lists`, I want to select 1 element at random
- from element 2 of `my_list_of_lists`, I want to select 1 element at random
- from element 3 of `my_list_of_lists`, I want to select 2 elements at random

Here are `my_list_of_lists` and `number_to_select`:

```
my_list_of_lists <- list(
  c(147, 313, 337, 546),
  c(35, 135, 281, 283, 325, 326, 357),
  c(311, 334, 403, 427, 436, 507, 520, 566, 595, 632))

number_to_select <- c(1, 1, 2)
```

I can do this individually no problem. For example:

```
sample(my_list_of_lists[[3]],number_to_select[[3]])
#[1] 520 436
```

But when I try to use `lapply`, I don't get it:

```
selected_vals = lapply(my_list_of_lists, function(x) { sample(x, number_to_select)})
selected_vals[[3]]
#[1] 334
```

How can I use `lapply` to choose 1 element from the first list, 1 element from the second list, and 2 elements from the third list?

Comment: Note that what you have is actually a list of vectors, not a list of lists.

Comment: The edit changed my output - but it may well have been a list of vectors.

Answer (score 2):

You want to iterate over multiple collections, so you should use `Map`. For example

```
Map(sample, my_list_of_lists, number_to_select)
```

will do what you want by calling `sample` multiple times with corresponding values of `my_list_of_lists` and `numbers_to_select`.

Comment: or `mapply(FUN=sample, my_list_of_lists, size=c(1,1,2))`

Comment: @jogo this is what I ended up using and it worked perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a corresponding solution with `purrr::map2` from the `tidyverse`. You can't use `lapply` here because you want to map over two objects simultaneously. In general, it's helpful to provide your input in a reproducible format rather than just the `head()`.

```r
library(tidyverse)
my_list_of_lists <- list(
  c(147, 313, 337, 546),
  c(35, 135, 281, 283, 325, 326, 357),
  c(311, 334, 403, 427, 436, 507, 520, 566, 595, 632)
)

number_to_select <- c(1, 1, 2)

selected_vals <- map2(
  .x = my_list_of_lists,
  .y = number_to_select,
  .f = function(x,y) base::sample(x, y)
  )
print(selected_vals)
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 546
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 283
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] 507 311
```

Created on 2018-03-14 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).